# How can I merge this query so that it returns only one column?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
Player Name         Nationality
--------------------------------
Romelu Lukaku       Belgian
Christian Pulisic   American
Kai Havertz         German
Masoun Mount        British
Reece James         British
Edouard Mendy       French
N'Golo Kante        French
Hakim Ziyech        Morrocan
Timo Werner         German
Thiago Silva        Brazilian
Ross Barkley        British
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE([Player Name], 'Reece', 'John'),
    REPLACE([Player Name], 'Christian', 'Chris') 
FROM 
    Players
```

This query returns two columns rather than just one. How can I make the query one so that only one column gets returned?

Comment: use the SQL function `CONCAT`.  (see appropriate documentation, depending on the DBMS used.)

Comment: BTW: Your query is probably not doing what you intent to do because the replacement is only done when executing the query, and the contents of the database is not changed.  Did you perhaps wanted to do and `UPDATE` ?

Comment: You could simply replace the comma between your two replaces by the concatenation operator of your DB, mostly that's + or ||

Comment: Specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION` tojoin rows vertically

```
SELECT REPLACE([Player Name], 'Reece', 'John') as name FROM Players
UNION
SELECT REPLACE([Player Name], 'Christian', 'Chris') FROM Players
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, if I wanted to update the records permanently with the values above would I just change SELECT with UPDATE for both lines?

Comment: no you would nest it `UPDATE Players SET Player Name] = REPLACE(REPLACE([Player Name], 'Christian', 'Chris') , 'Reece', 'John')`

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for that great tip. I think there is a '[' missing before Player Name] or is it meant to be like that?.

Comment: yes you are right